# web3.eth.abi.encodeParameter for array of structs

Tags: solidity, web3js

Here I have a smart contract with one method `batch` that accepts array of users to push into `users` state variable.

```solidity
contract UserFactory {
  struct User {
    string name;
    uint age;
  }

  User[] users;

  function batch(User[] _users) public {
    // logic to add _users to users array
  }
}
```

Here on the JavaScript side I'm using `web3.eth.abi.encodeParameter` to create `bytes` type for some design purpose. But the problem is I have no idea how to encode `User[]` with `encodeParameter`. There is a solution to create a type like `tuple(string,uint256)[]` and pass `[['John', 26], ['Doe', 99]]` but again for design purpose I have to use the `{name: "John", age: 26}` so my alternative solution wont help.

```js
// Trying to somehow create with array of users like [{name: "John", age: 26}, {name: "Doe", age: 99}]
const payload = web3.eth.abi.encodeParameter(
  {
    User: {
      name: "string",
      age: "uint256",
    },
  },
  {
    name: "John",
    age: 26,
  }
);

// This one working fine
const alternativePayload = const payload = web3.eth.abi.encodeParameter(
  'tuple(string,uint256)[]',
  [['John', 26], ['Doe', 99]]
);
```

Comment: `encodeParameter` is a low level function it doesn't seem to be user friendly. I'd suggest to write a wrapper function accept an input like the description and create the tuple parameter for `encodeParameter`.